# What would be the coding for Cyclic rotation in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Like, I want to make a function that can take 2 strings as input, and then output me whether the strings are cyclic or not?
For example, CAR, ARC, RCA are the cyclic rotations of themselves.

Comment: I tried to find solution, m=but I don't know why mid is not working

Comment: I am a beginner, who don't know all functions, but my mind says, first we should check the first character to the last and second character, then perform similar function. But don't have exact idea how to implement it.

Comment: sounds like your in class lol.  start by comparing the string lengths, then treat the strings like arrays and compare the indexes in the manner you wish inside of a loop.

Comment: @safarov That is one cool link.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function cyclic( $first, $second ) {
    for( $i = 0, $j = strlen( $first ); $i < $j; $i ++ ) {
        $cycled = substr( $first, $i ) . substr( $first, 0, $i );
        if( $cycled === $second ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump( cyclic( 'CAR', 'ARC' ) );
```

It's pretty simple, really. First, calculate a "cycled version". If the cycled version equals the second string, you're done. If it didn't, try again. Oh, and you can check how [substr](http://nl.php.net/substr) works in the PHP manual.